Priorities for Tachanun for those who say Viddui
Given that saying Vidui in Tachanun is a relatively new custom among Sefaradim, nusach Sefard and Ari, I would like to know if it takes priority, such as if one only has time to say it or Tehillim 25 (or Tehillim 6 for nusach Sefard), which should one say?
For those who advocate for everyone to say Tehillim 6, should people prioritise it over Tehillim 25 (where applicable) and Vidui?
